# can c++ macro set class pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, macros

i have this situation 
i have map that i iterate :
int counter = 1;

```
bool ReelGameObj::setInitWithSpriteFrameName(std::map<std::string,std::string> imageComponentMap)
{
    int counter = 1;
    for (auto keyvalue : imageComponentMap ) {
        std::string pngName = keyvalue.second ;
        SET_SPRITE(counter,pngName);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

in the header i have :

```
 private:


    Sprite* reel_1;
    Sprite* reel_2;
    Sprite* reel_3;
    Sprite* reel_4;
    Sprite* reel_5;
```

i was thinking about dynamclly set the pointers using MACRO to avoid if/else and to do something more generic but with no lack 
this macro fail

```
#define SET_SPRITE(__NUMBER__,spriteFrameName) this->reel_##__NUMBER__ = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(spriteFrameName);
```

is there any better way ?

Comment: Why don't you just use an array of `Sprite*`? It would be declared as `Sprite *sprites[5];` As a side note, I'm a fan of using the **pre**-increment (or decrement) when you don't need the side-effect anyway.

Comment: Consecutively numbered variable names are often a sign that you need an array or vector instead, **especially** if you need to access them by index.

Comment: Thanks just wanted to be sure on this

Answer (score 4):

You can't do exactly what you've written, because `counter` needs to be a pre-processor constant for this to work (That is, a macro).

Surely it would be better to use an array, e.g. `Sprite* reel[5];`, or even better, a std::vector reel;`?